# How to wait for result of PromptAsync in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

I've installed the Acr.UserDialogs NuGet-Package and am trying to open a prompt and wait for the result.. I've tried several ways but don't get it working.
My first attempt looked like this and worked at least sometimes:

```
bool validInput = false;
PromptResult pResult;

PromptConfig pConfig = new PromptConfig
{
    Message = "Some message",
    MaxLength = 10,
    Placeholder = "Number...",

    OnTextChanged = args =>
    {
        if (args.Value.Length < 1)
            args.IsValid = false;

        foreach (char c in args.Value)
        {
            if (!char.IsNumber(c))
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

pResult = await UserDialogs.Instance.PromptAsync(pConfig);

if(pResult.Ok)
{
    validInput = true;
}

if (validInput)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage()));
}
```

But sometimes the prompt doesn't shows up and *pResult.Ok* is anyway *true*.
I get that I obviously have to wait until I got the result... but how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with xamarin forms but, I'm guessing there can be an event on `PromptConfig` like `Completed` and in that event, you can check the result maybe.

Comment: There is an OnAction event on PromptConfig. To use that I had to change `pResult = await UserDialogs.Instance.PromptAsync(pConfig)` to `UserDialogs.Instance.Prompt(pConfig)` ...     The OnAction event now looks like this `OnAction = args =>
                            {
                                if(args.Ok)
                                    Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage());
                            }`. But the Prompt still only shows up sometimes and in the cases it don't shows up, `args.Ok` in `OnAction` is `true` ... I don't get it. Maybe I should ask the developers on git

Comment: By the way, PromptConfig is also a class of Acr.UserDialogs

Comment: dont use acr userdialogs. just use rg popups and create your own prompt config. it will look even more beautiful and you will have more control over usage and layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone should run into the same problem.. I think the reason, why the "await" didn't do what it was supposed to do, was the Android-Emulator.

I don't know why, but on a real Android smartphone with Android 6.0 (the emulator has also Android 6.0 installed) the code from above works absolutely fine. And also on another real Android smartphone with Android 7.0 everything worked...